# Comparar valores de matrices

Tags: python, algoritmos, ingenieria-del-software

Estaba haciendo una especie de prueba de coeficiente intelectual (parece que fallé) y ahora no puedo dejar de pensar en esto, ¡tal vez alguien aquí pueda ayudarme!

La cuestión es que tengo dos matrices, llamémoslas S y T.
S[0...N]
T[0...N]

El problema planteado es: tengo que comparar ambas matrices y realizar un seguimiento de cuántas veces S[i] > T[i]. La cuestión es que solo puedo usar una variable. Ambas cadenas son constantes, al igual que sus longitudes, solo puedo cambiar los valores de "i". Entonces tengo que usar "i" para iterar entre ellos y también almacenar cuántas veces se cumplió S[i] > T[i].
Pd: Usar "For n..." También cuenta como declarar una nueva variable.

Comment: `sum(1 if x[0] > x[1] else 0 for x in zip(S, T))`

Comment: Ummmm, ¿Se permite usar la biblioteca estándar sin restricciones?, porque lo que me pide el cuerpo es "hacer trampas" aplicando un enfoque de programación funcional, se resuelve sin ciclos implícitos y sin una sola variable solo con map y sum...

Comment: Desafortunadamente no, el tema es hacerlo en pseudocódigo, solo sirven los bucles for, los while, los do, todo eso en general, pero ninguna librería de python... **Por lo que da a entender el enunciado, es algo rebuscado. Y consta de un ciclo for dentro de un if**

Comment: Seguramente la solución más sencilla sería algo parecido a lo que propuso @CandidMoe `sum(x>y for x,y in zip(S,T))` aunque imagino que buscas algo así como:
`count=0
for i in range(min(len(S), len(T))):
 if S[i]>T[i]:
  count+=1`

Comment: Exactamente, y esa es la manera mas fácil utilizando python, pero debe haber alguna manera de iterar y almacenar todo en una sola variable. Porque en ese caso no me acepta la respuesta pues i es una variable extra, solo se puede utilizar count

Comment: Checkee y la pista es que **solo utiliza un bucle While y un if**. Eso es todo lo que dice

Comment: Me alegro de que te hayan ayudado! Pero para la proxima, no edites la pregunta si es para convertirla en un agradecimiento. El objetivo de editar la pregunta es mejorarla y/o agregar información extra relacionada a dicha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dada las restricciones, lo primero que se me ocurre es recurrir al módulo.

Una forma de almacenar las veces que se cumple la condición en la misma variable que se usa como índice es incrementar la variable en `N` (siendo `N` la longitud de los arrays). A la hora de indizar basta con aplicar el módulo para obtener el indice válido dentro del rango. El numero de veces que se cumple la condición sera la división entera de `i` entre `N` menos 1 (`i // N - 1`), algo así:

```python
i = 0
while i == 0 or i % len(S) != 0:
    if S[i % len(S)] > T[i % len(S)]:
        i += len(S)
    i += 1
print(i // len(S) - 1)
```

Si nos dan la longitud en una constante, digamos `N`, podemos prescindir de tanta llamada a `len`:

```python
N = 7
S = [1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 7, 2]
T = [2, 1, 6, 9, 11, 6, 8]

i = 0
while i == 0 or i % N != 0:
    if S[i % N] > T[i % N]:
        i += N
    i += 1
print(i // N - 1)
```

En realidad seria perfecto para un `do-while`, pero en Python no existe, lo mismo en C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const size_t N = 7;
    const int S[] = {1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 7, 2};
    const int T[] = {2, 1, 6, 9, 11, 6, 8};

    size_t i = 0;  // Cuidado con el overflow, max i = (N+1)N
    do {
        if (S[i % N] > T[i % N]) {
            i += N;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i % N != 0);
    
   printf("%zu", i / N - 1);
   
   return 0;
}
```

**Nota:** Si los arrays están vacíos el código generara obviamente un `ZeroDivisionError`, si se debe contemplar esta posibilidad bastaría con agregar un condicional.

---

### Bonus

Si se permitiera usar Python sin restricciones, yo recurriria a programación funcional:

```python
from operator import gt

S = [1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 7, 2]
T = [2, 1, 6, 9, 11, 6, 8]

print(sum(map(gt, S, T)))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Que grande. Funciona perfecto y cumple con todo!

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente esta no sea la forma esperada de resolverlo pero se puede hacer sin variables utilizando funciones recursivas:

```
S = [1, 2, 3]
T = [0, 1, 4]

def veces(S, T):
    def veces_rec(S, T, total):
        if (len(S) == 0 or len(T) == 0):
            return total
        else:
            return veces_rec(S[1:], T[1:], total + (1 if S[0] > T[0] else 0))
        
    return veces_rec(S, T, 0)

print(veces(S,T)) # 2
```

La primera función `veces` llama a la función recursiva `veces_rec` con `S`, `T` y un parámetro más, que es el total de veces que hemos encontrado que `S[i]` es mayor que `T[i]`. Inicialmente pasamos un 0 para que nos sirva en el caso base en caso de que los arrays estén vacíos.

El caso base de la función recursiva es que alguno de los arrays estén vacíos, en ese caso devolveremos el total que llevemos acumulado.

El otro caso es que los arrays tengan uno o más elementos, en ese caso volveremos a llamar recursivamente a la función, pero esta vez pasaremos la cola (tail) de los arrays (es decir, todos los elementos menos el primero, expresado con `:1`). Después, si la cabeza (head) del array `S` (es decir, el primer elemento del array) es mayor que la cabeza del array `T` le añadiremos uno al total, sino añadiremos un cero y pasaremos ese valor a la función recursiva.

Comment: "se puede hacer sin variables" -> Al final un parámetro es una variable más de alguna manera. Si te impiden declarar variables, tampoco puedes declarar parámetros imagino

Comment: Es otra manera de resolverlo, se ve bastante explicito. Creo que tambien funciona, muchas gracias!